# In network programming, must the accepting end close both sockets?

Tags: python, c, sockets

I raised a question earlier, and one of the answers involved another question.

That is to say, in general, the accepting end should create two sockets to establish the accepting end. like this:

#### Python

```py
from socket import *
sockfd = socket(...)
# ...
client_sockfd, addr = sockfd.accept()
# ...
client_sockfd.close()
sockfd.close()
```

#### C

```c
int sockfd, client_sockfd;
sockfd = socket(...);
// ...
client_sockfd = accept(sockfd, ...);
// ...
shutdown(client_sockfd, 2);
shutdown(sockfd, 2);
close(client_sockfd);
close(sockfd);
```

---

So can we skip the task of creating the `client_sockfd` variable? like this:

#### Python

```py
sockfd = socket(...)
# ...
sockfd, addr = sockfd.accept()
# ...
sockfd.close()
```

#### C

```c
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
socklen_t client_size = sizeof(client);
sockfd = socket(...);
// ...
sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_size);
```

Or it could be like this:

#### Python

```py
sockfd = socket(...)
# ...
client_sockfd, addr = sockfd.accept()
sockfd.close()
# ...
client_sockfd.close()
```

#### C

```c
int sockfd = socket(...);
int client_sockfd;
// ...
client_sockfd = accept(sockfd, ...);
shutdown(sockfd, 2);
close(sockfd);
// ...
shutdown(client_sockfd, 2);
close(client_sockfd);
```

As shown in the above code, can we use only one socket to complete the accepting end of the entire network programming? Is there any problem with this? (At least I didn't have any problems writing the program like this myself)

Comment: When you say receiving end, do you mean accepting end. In most cases, both ends receive and transmit.

Comment: Yes, I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So can we skip the task of creating the client_sockfd variable?

For connection-oriented protocols such as TCP, no.  The two sockets involved on the receiving side of such a service are of different kinds and serve different purposes, both required.

The socket that (in C) you create via the `socket()` function and use with the `accept()` function is often called a "server socket".  It's job is to wait for incoming connection requests, and when it accepts one, to prepare an endpoint for communication with that request's remote peer.  The resulting endpoint is represented by the *second* (and third, and fourth ...) socket, obtained via successful calls to `accept()`.

You use the server socket to accept connections, potentially having multiple active connections at the same time, and you use each of the others ("peer sockets", if you like) to communicate with a specific client.  Closing a peer socket terminates the connection with the associated remote peer.  Closing the server socket makes the system stop accepting new connections at its address / port.

You propose this alternative:

> ```
> int sockfd;
> struct sockaddr_in server, client;
> socklen_t client_size = sizeof(client);
> sockfd = socket(...);
> // ...
> sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_size);
> ```

That's not technically wrong, but as soon as you assign the result of `accept()` to variable `sockfd`, you no longer have access to the server socket (supposing you did not store its file descriptor in another variable, which would moot the question).  This is a resource leak.  Moreover, it prevents you from accepting any subsequent connections at the designated address / port.  Until the process terminates (if then), you will not even be able to create a new server socket for that port, as the existing one will be in the way.

---

All of this is different for datagram-oriented sockets -- there are no connections to `accept()`, and no inherent distinction between server sockets and peer sockets for such protocols.  But based on the appearance of `accept()` calls in your example code, that's not what you are asking about.

Comment: What you (and many others) call a “server socket”, is better called a “listener socket” (more technically a “passive socket”). The other end is the “connecting socket” (technically “active socket”).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I acknowledge that there are multiple names for the kinds of sockets.  I submit that the fact that I am with many others in using the term "server socket" contradicts your assertion that it would be *better* to use a different term.

Comment: I suddenly understood how to implement multithreaded sockets in network programming, and your words made me realize it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the problem with terminology comes when you add an active (connecting) socket to a server, and a passive (listening) socket to the client.

Answer (score 3):

You are always creating two sockets: the server socket and the first accepted client socket.  When you close them is up to you.

Using the same name for both in Python will still close the server socket (eventually) because the object reference count goes to zero, but in C you leak the socket.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example

```
from socket import *
sockfd = socket(...)
# ...
client_sockfd, addr = sockfd.accept()
# ...
client_sockfd.close()
sockfd.close()
```

`sockfd` is the descriptor for the listener. It can be re-used.
After closing `client_sockfd`, you can `accept` again.

E.g.

```
from socket import *
sockfd = socket(...)
while not is_finished:
   client_sockfd, addr = sockfd.accept()
   # ...
   client_sockfd.close()
sockfd.close()
```

You can `accept` more than one socket (into different fd variables), and talk with multiple clients. However, this requires some concurrent programming.

Comment: "*If you pass a number higher than 1 to `socket`, ...*" - I think you mean `listen()` instead. `socket()` doesn't have such a parameter. `listen()` is missing in these examples, but is needed for `accept()` to work. The number passed to `listen()` is the backlog size, it merely controls the max number of clients that can be pending waiting to be `accept()`'ed. Regardless of the backlog size, you can always work with multiple `accept`'ed clients at a time, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure if there is a "problem", but it seems relevant to explain whats going on here:**

When you call `sockfd.accept()` it blocks until a connection comes in. When one does come in it returns *another* socket which "represents" the connection, and can be used to send and receive data on the connection. The reason for the multiple calls to `socket.close()` is that in your first example `client_sockfd.close()` *only closes the connection*. You can still call `sockfd.accept()` again to receive another connection, and many socket servers use `socket.accept()` in a `while` loop. Calling `sockfd.close()` will close `sockfd`, usually when no further connections (calls to `sockfd.accept()`) need to be made.